# kivy- how to add function after press MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am using a floating action button speed dial in kivymd. I want to add functions (navigate to the another screen) after press singular buttons. Can anyone tell me please by an example how do I do it?

```
<HomeScreen>:
    name: "home"
  MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
        data: 
            {'home': 'Domov',
            'lightning-bolt': 'Ciele',
            'notebook': 'Moje testy'}

<TestScreen>:
    name: "test"

<GoalsScreen>:
    name: "goals"
    
<HistoryScreen>:
    name: "history"
```

I tried something like normall buttons, but it doesn´
t work.

```
on_release:
         root.manager.current = "test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `callback` to the `MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial`:

```
  MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
        callback: app.call
        data: 
            {'home': 'Domov',
            'lightning-bolt': 'Ciele',
            'notebook': 'Moje testy'}
```

with the `call()` method defined in the app:

```
def call(self, button):
    print('called from', button)
```

Then any button press will trigger the `call()` method.

Comment: yes i understand, thank you so much. But when I want to each button doing something else?

Comment: You can choose what to do based on the `Button` that was pressed. Something like `if button.icon == "home":`.